# How can I create a query using Realm that contains a word in a text string that begins with certain characters?

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to create a query that ignores potentially confusing prefixes. So if a data field contains:

> - "The combination was beautiful"
> - "The bin is full"
> - "The binder is empty"

And if the search term is 'bin', how can I create a query which will show only the second and third results?

When using a simple .contains, all 3 data would show up.

Comment: Maybe search " bin" (a space before) ? Realm doesn't support regular expression right now which is a bit difficult to deal with this kind of queries. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1377 .

Comment: Thanks, that not a bad workaround. The regular expression method would be ideal

Comment: There is a github issue on regex: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1377